# Prevention or workaround for browser caching form data on jQuery ajax POST (.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I am working on an application using .NET MVC where I have an interface with 3 "tabs", each with form fields and a "Delete Tab" button. All three tabs have the same form fields (first name, last name). Screenshot included as an example. The actual form has a lot more fields than this, but I think this will be sufficient to explain the situation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJlHJ.png

The setup:

1. Assume tabs 1 and 2 are filled out with names, but tab 3 fields are empty.
2. "Delete Tab" is pressed on tab 2. An ajax post is sent to the server, and the server returns a partial view of the same content, but now includes just two tabs since one tab was deleted. The data from tabs 1 and 3 are applied to the two available tabs because we deleted tab 2 and no longer want that data.
3. This partial view replaces the entire tab section using jQuery .empty().html(partialView).

The problem:

I expect that tab 1 will contain the original data before the ajax post, and tab 2 will have empty form fields because it takes on the values of the original tab 3. What actually happens is that tab 2 has the same data it did before the post, as if it was not deleted. From the testing I have done, this seems to be because the browser will autofill null values in the fields with any non-null data it has cached for form fields with the same name. Since tab 2 form data is being replaced with the null values from tab 3, the original contents of tab 2 still show up. I am not positive as to whether this is a browser or javascript/jQuery issue. I tested this in Firefox, Chrome, and Edge.

Is there a good solution to get around this? Everything I have come up with has been hacky and what I would consider error-prone code. I would prefer to not resort to manually coding empty spaces into each form field or something like that.

Comment: you should probably include your code in the post... seems like the model should be tied to the tabs/fields with unique/indexed names/ids.  If this is really is a browser auto-filling issue, there are some tricks to get around that using duplicate invisible fields.  (not sure modern browsers would need this...)

Comment: What's your  form field  code like ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like autocomplete, you can turn it off by setting the attribute to off on your input

```
<input type="test" name="fname" autocomplete="off">
```